# Facebook share button current URL

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I want to add a share button to my website but notice I have two similar options:

1. [Share button](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button)
2. [Share dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog)

Are they different and how could I show a share button for the dialog option?

Also, for the button code it says HTML5/data-href "defaults to the current URL" which I want, so would I simply delete data-href from the button code or just leave the URL empty?

Comment: _“how could I show a share button for the dialog option”_ - you’d need to make your own button, and then call the dialog when that button gets clicked.

Answer (score 0):

**Share Button**

Social Plugin that comes with a predefined button, you cannot change the appearance. Simple to include.

**Share Dialog**

Use your own button/link/whatever and call `FB.ui` to open the Dialog.